# Spikes appearing on the UART pins of Microcontroller when connecting to supply

Tags: uart, motor-controller, esd, spike

I am using STM32G0c8t6 microcontroller to make a BLDC motor controller. I am connecting the Rx and Tx of UART to a VCU and they are sharing the same battery. Apart from these, there is no other connection between them. And sometimes, for some unknown reason the microcontroller is getting shorted when UART is connected. It is not happening every time, so I am unable to monitor the voltages, etc. at the exact moment. On one of the damaged microcontroller, the Tx pin of microcontroller was shorted to ground and Vcc. Rx pin was intact.

While VCU is already powered on. When powering on the controller with the switch, I noticed certain waveforms. Interestingly, if I connect the controller's ground to the battery first and then the positive, these waveforms don't occur. However, when I connect the positive terminal of battery to controller first and then the ground, these waveforms appear most of the time. This is the sequence of connection.
[image]

[image]
The green circle shows the points where I captured waveforms.

Answer (score 2):

When the controller is turned off, it doesn't have any supply voltage available to it. This means that the voltage difference between its VCC and GND pins is 0V. Now, if you connect the battery positive to the controller, you're forcing VCC=30V (approximately). However, since GND is still disconnected, it still can't draw any current from the supply voltage. As a result, the voltage difference between VCC and GND is still 0V. This means that the voltage at the controller's GND pin will *also* be pulled up to 30V.

Now you have VCC=GND=30V, and since the UART TX pin is forced by the controller's ESD protection diodes to be somewhere between VCC and GND, it too is pulled to 30V. This will cause excess current to flow through the pin, killing it. The same happens to RX.

The solution is to **always leave GND (negative) connected and only switch VCC (positive)**.

Comment: I am using an XT60 connector for power supply. So when connecting, any one of the terminals could make contact first based on the angle at which the XT60 is connected together. So, unfortunately, there is no way make sure that ground is connected first. And always when the microcontroller is getting damaged, it is through the UART pins. how can it be protected? We tried TVS diodes too, but still the microcontroller got damaged.

Comment: @GladsonThomas The only way to protect it is to ensure that ground is always connected to the system before any other pins. There's no way around this. Whenever the UART pins are connected without a ground present, any current that flows will necessarily kill either the microcontroller or the VCU. Did you consider running a separate ground wire between the microcontroller and VCU? In general, all components of the system should share a single common ground that **cannot be disconnected**.

Answer (score 1):

Well, stop connecting the positive supply first if it solves the problem.

In general it should not be done anyway. Never connect data wires first and only later supply and/or ground wires.

When you do connect supply wire first, there will of course be 0V between supply and ground pins of the unpowered device. Therefore, everything on the unpowered board is at the supply voltage, when compared to ground level.

If you have any data pin connections then there will be current through data pins and there may be excessive voltages because MCU IO pins can't tolerate being connected to 12V or whatever battery voltage that is, any protection diodes will pass current and the supply caps of the unpowered board start to charge.

So the solution is to keep ground potentials alaways connected so anything powered or unpowered is at 0V compared to each other.

Still having one board powered and other unpowered while they share data connections may leak current through data pins, possibly causing problems and even damage.

Designing systems that can be powered or unpowered when being connected together need careful design how to avoid problems or damage.

Comment: I am using an XT60 connector for power supply. So when connecting, any one of the terminals could make contact first based on the angle at which the XT60 is connected together. So, unfortunately, there is no way make sure that ground is connected first. And always when the microcontroller is getting damaged, it is through the UART pins. how can it be protected? We tried TVS diodes too, but still the microcontroller got damaged.

Comment: @GladsonThomas Then change the connector, or stop plugging it while the system is live, i.e. maybe the connector should be at the battery so you can disconnect and connect the whole system, so that VCU, Controller and Display are always connected together, or have a separate ground wire between them, or use a real interface chips that are high voltage tolerant on the UARTs, but they also require equal ground potential even if it there was a 70V tolerant RS-485 bus. Do not disconnect the ground.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMIgS1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

@GLADSON THOMAS I think this will work, by adding a zener diode on each pin of 3.3V
@justme @jonathan s.

Comment: I think this will make things worse. Why do you assume this will help, what is the logic behind it?

Comment: like the voltage spike is for 100 ms the zener diode will clamp the voltage on the UART pins to 3.3 volts, @justme

Comment: if not where could it fail

Comment: When one board is unpowered, it has 0V between all data and power supplies. When you connect positive wire first to this board, it is still having 0V at supplies and data pins in reference to it's ground, but this ground is 30V above the ground of board with ground wire connected. Basically the diodes now help killing the other boards with 30V.

Comment: or any kind of isolator can isolate the pins @justme

Comment: like OPTOCOUPLER